# How to write an if or statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

this is my code:

```
if ($("#target").val() == "money") {
    //alert("you asked for money!");
    $("h1").text(bigMoney);
    return false;
}
```

I would like to say if the val() = money OR wealth. I have tried using || but I am clearly using it wrong :

```
 if ($("#target").val() == "money" || $("#target").val() == "wealth") {
        //alert("you asked for money!");
        $("h1").text(bigMoney);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `||` is correct .. You have some other problem

Comment: Print the value of `$("#target").val()` to make sure it isn't something unexpected. The code you've pasted works.

Comment: Try enclosing each condition in parentheses:  if (($("#target").val() == "money" )|| ($("#target").val() == "wealth"))

Comment: @DOK: Won't make a difference.

Comment: Your question would benefit from a larger section of code as the section you have given does not show any error, therefore this question cannot be answered in its current form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work. Make sure the string is the same case and has no trailing or leading whitespace:

```
var text = $.trim($('#target').val().toLowerCase());
```

You can also use `indexOf` with an array:

```
if (['money', 'wealth'].indexOf(text) !== -1) {
    // The text is in the array
}
```